# how to recovery ext4.vhdx after cmd: wsl --unregister ubuntu?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

i accidently trusted bing ai says:i can run unregistered cmd ,it will not delete ext4.vhdx .  i have so many important work on wsl and have no backup.

and i immediately stop write file to volume d and set it to readonly:

i tried winfr cmd,not find ext4.vhdx file .
i tried set the volume to read only and use disk drill , it not find my file.
I tried diskgenius, it find ext4.vhdx , but 0KB . the actually size is about 30GB like .

Comment: The file is already permanently gone. There isn’t anything you can do

Comment: really? why so certain? the unregistered cmd exec fill 0 operation  with file sectors?

Comment: or i completely lost file control block ?

Comment: or some of my recovery  trying operation cause ?

Comment: I am certain due to my decades of experience

Comment: ok. then i maybe would have to accept the permeant loss.

Comment: anyway . thank you .@Ramhound .

Comment: `exec fill 0 operation` nope, but then in the case of SSD, TRIM is triggered after file deletion, so you pretty much get the equivalent. (Technically it is so-to-speak possible to salvage pieces the image with some really serious / professional equipments that bypasses the SSD controller, I suppose, if done before actual garbage collection).

Comment: This is why I copy my wsl ext4.vhdx to a separate drive every Saturday. Just done it. Compress it with 7zip, also. 9 GB zip archive. Keep the last 2 copies.

Comment: Professional ! @TomYan  Great explanation! Now I can completely  drop the idea of recovery  forever .

Comment: Yeah. I guess I will choose multiple auto backup files approach, such as clound storage .and Timer task backup plan locally. What a expensive lesson cause by data recovery. @MichaelHarvey